# deletion in multiple tables with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables in my sql database:

```
assignresources
tasks 
project
```

the `project` table has columns

```
ID(pk),
Guid,
name, 
startdate, 
enddate
```

the other 2 tables have the `Guid` columns with some other names. How can i delete related  rows in all the tables(with matching `Guid` values) depending on row deletion in `Project` table Via `ID` column?

Comment: Can you post DDLs of your tables?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use InnoDB engine, and define ON DELETE CASCADE. So when the row in the parent table is deleted, related data in all the child tables will be automatically deleted.

For example, for tasks table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
`tasks_Guid` int(11) NOT NULL,
INDEX (`tasks_Guid`),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`tasks_Guid`) 
    REFERENCES `project` (`Guid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) TYPE=InnoDB;
```

[MySql on delete cascade concept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764493/mysql-on-delete-cascade-concept)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this (XXXXX = project ID):

```
DELETE project . * , tasks . * , assignresources . * 
FROM project 
LEFT JOIN tasks ON tasks.Guid = project.Guid 
LEFT JOIN assignresources ON assignresources.Guid = project.Guid 
WHERE project.ID = XXXXX
```